# Position odd/even list items in a menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu

I have an unordered list with n items, which should be transformed into a horizontal menu like [the picture below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3StP9.png). I was able to select all odd items and move them to the end of the list, creating the two menu rows, but I find the centering rather difficult.

[image]

Code I've used, but cannot center:

```
jQuery('#ja-mainnav ul li').css({'float':'left', 'display': 'block', 'margin-left': 'auto', 'margin-right': 'auto' });
jQuery('#ja-mainnav ul li:odd:first').css({'clear':'both', 'margin-left':'40px'});
jQuery('#ja-mainnav ul li:odd').insertAfter('#ja-mainnav ul li:last');
```

Comment: Try:

float: none;
display: inline;
clear: none;
margin: 0 auto;

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
li {
    background:red;
    border:1px solid black;
}
div#ja-mainnav {
    width:150px;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
<div id="ja-mainnav">
    <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
        <li>Item 4</li>
        <li>Item 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and JS

```
jQuery('#ja-mainnav ul li').css({
    'display': 'inline-block'
});
jQuery('#ja-mainnav ul li:odd').insertAfter('#ja-mainnav ul li:last');
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/Tkgjf/